# How to get Jira data and make it displayed in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira, dashboard

I have my project dashboards in JIRA which i need to establish in Jenkins once the project build is done successfully. When i search over internet everything says how to integrate and once the build is finished Jira Plugin will raise/update issues to JIRA. But I want to get the data from JIRA and display in Jenkins dashboard like we display cucumber or Junit reports.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What info are you looking for exactly?  A Jenkins project build contains one-or-more commits from source-control, and presumably each of those commits points at one-or-more JIRAs.  You potentially have Jenkin's builds containing multiple JIRAs.  It's not clear what you are trying to see exactly.

Comment: Hi @JeffBennett, do you aware that any of the plugins will pull the data and display in Jenkins from Jira?